# The difference between creating object before/after window.onload

Tags: javascript, object, onload

As below, I create a function displayMsg that displays the content of "object1.msg", which is build after onload event, but it shows undefined.

But if i put

```
var object1 = new testObject("Hello");
```

before window.onload, no matter before/after displayMsg() function, it works.

Why is that? and what is the program executing order difference between these two? Thanks...

```
function testObject(msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

function displayMsg() {
    document.getElementById("msgbox").innerHTML = object1.msg;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var object1 = new testObject("Hello");
    displayMsg();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onLoad event is triggered when the page or element (You can use onLoad with DOM elements) is loaded and rendered, so the rest of the javascript code that is located inline is previously read and executed.

What probably happens with you code is that you are defining the object instance variable inside the onLoad callback, hereby the "object1" is out of the scope.

You can try with this:

```js
var object1;   // Variable is defined in the global scope

function testObject(msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

function displayMsg() {
    document.getElementById("msgbox").innerHTML = object1.msg;
}

window.onload = function() {
    object1 = new testObject("Hello");
    displayMsg();
}
```

```html
<div id="msgbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `object1` inside a function, therefore it's in that function's scope, and cannot be accessed from another scope.

Try this:

```
function testObject(msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

function displayMsg(object) {
    document.getElementById("msgbox").innerHTML = object.msg;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var object1 = new testObject("Hello");
    displayMsg(object);
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's it! .... Can't believe I waste several hours thinking this question... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your `object1` object in the scope of the window.onload function.
That means there is no object1 in your display message function.

You can try passing the object as a parameter to your `displayMsg()` function or just migrate your entire code into the onload function.

**EDIT**

Just to awnser your question of the load order: Every script that you include gets executed as soon as its loaded by the browser. Using `window.onload` will delay all code in that function to the point where every single script of the page is loaded. And also note that the order in wich you put scripts in your html file **does matter**!

Comment: Nice! Thanks my friend.